# F1 Visa Duration and Passport Expiration

Tags: passport-stamps, f1-visas

I am planning to attend my masters in US for upcoming Fall 2022. My passport is expiring on January 2024. However, my course duration is from Sept 2022 till June 2024. When the F1  visa gets stamped, what would be the duration for it? The end date would be the passport expiry date or according to the course duration?

Note: I am from India. I can only renew my passport before a year from the time of expiration which would be January 2023.

Comment: It should be noted that US visas are solely for entry, and the visa's expiration date has nothing to do with how long you can stay in the US. So as long as your visa is valid on the date you enter, it shouldn't matter how much longer it is valid, unless you plan to leave the US and enter again in the future (on which date you will need a valid visa).

Answer (score 1):

The expiry date of US visa (F-1 or B-1/B-2) is independent of the expiry date of the traveler's passport. That is, the expiry date of the visa may be later than that of the passport. The exact duration of the visa depends on the visa type and the agreement between the US government and the passport-holder's home country.